# Assign a parent to an existing entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore which is already populated with entities. However, they haven't been arranged into entity groups (a.k.a parent-child relationships). My entity Kinds are:

```
team = Team.get_by_key_name('Plants')
query = Plants.all()
```

The `plants` haven't been assigned to the `Plants` team yet:

```
query = Plants.all().ancestor(team)
plants = query.fetch(50)
# This will result in an empty list
```

I would like to assign them to the team now:

```
query = Plants.all()
plants = query.fetch(50)

for p in plants:
  # This isn't right
  p.parent = team

db.put(plants)
```

When I try to query again based on `ancestor`:

```
query = Plants.all().ancestor(team)
plants = query.fetch(50)
# This still results in an empty list
```

**Question:** How do I assign a parent to an already existing entity?

Comment: Short answer: You can't - parent entities are determined at creation time. Long answer: See waffle's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience the easiest way to do this is to create a new entity copied with all the exact same info, and set the parent appropriately on this new entity.

This is because the parent becomes part of an entity's key (hence why you need to pass any existing parent to `db.Key`, or `get_by_key_name`, etc for them to work properly), so it's not changeable in the way you describe (or at least, not as far as I know).

Edit:
Xion brings up a good point that I forgot to mention.  When replacing the previous object with the new one, you also have to take care of any `ReferenceProperty` and `ListProperty(db.Key)` that may have pointed to the old object.  I guess the lesson of the day here is to design and think about entity groups more carefully before putting down any data.

Comment: Note that creating new entity will require to change all `ReferenceProperty' values that point to the old one.

Comment: An alternative is to make sure that going forward all new entities are assigned a parent upon creation, and then change your query logic to do three things: 1) run the query you previous used, 2) run a new query that specifies the ancestor, 3) union the two datasets. This provides strong consistency so long as your entities are immutable. If you mutate entities that were created prior to the introduction of you parent-setting logic then those mutations will not be strongly consistent.