# Google App Engine, BigTable and model evolution

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, jpa, bigtable

I am currently playing with Spring/JPA/Google App Engine, and there is an issue that I am worrying about.

The cool thing with GAE is, once my mapping is defined, I just need to insert data and everything associated to it is stored too.

However, if I happen to change my mapping, how can I do with my previous data ? Do I have to create migration scripts each time something has changed ? Is there a way to use Liquibase or something like that in this case ? Or is there another way to handle these changes on existing data ?

Thanks a lot for your help!
Rolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of those changes, but in most cases, at least some light updating will be required.  One big thing to keep in mind is parent-child relationships (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832575/assign-a-parent-to-an-existing-entity/6834038#6834038) for more details) and entity groups while design; since parents become part of an entity key, they are very much immutable.  Same with key names.

Another thing is that app engine entities are schemaless; for example if you have some class `Foo` and you suddenly add a property, `prop = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)` to it, all existing `Foo` entities will not have `prop` set to True (though new ones will).  Likewise, you will have to manage `ReferenceProperty`s and `ListProperty(db.Key)` manually.  App Engine does have a `_set` operator to help with this, but to be honest I've found it to be a bit unreliable, with `_set`s coming out empty when I knew for a fact that they should not be.  Regardless, here's the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) on using the `_set` functionality.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but the links are related to Python, not Java.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  The question wasn't explicitly labelled Java, so I figured either would be OK.  If you're working in Java, the `_set` stuff doesn't apply to you, but the points I raised are still valid, even if the code to deal with them will look different.